# Drawing a videostream using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, wxwidgets

I have a relatively simple application which currently utilizes OpenCV to grab an image from a camera using `cv::VideoCapture` and view the resulting image in a window using `imshow()` running on OS X El Capitan.

In between I'm doing some basic image modification but this is not crucial to my problem.

Since the GUI implemented by OpenCV is pretty basic I decided to redo it using wxWidgets. I got it basically running similarly to the implementation [linked](http://larryo.org/work/information/wxopencv/) in the tutorial section of wxWidgets. (Updated it to C++11 etc. but the idea is pretty much identical. Code is located on [github](https://github.com/heinemml/wxOpenCV).)

Now heres my problem: In best cases I get half the framerate as I get with the OpenCV only solution. OpenCV uses qt underneath. But when I look into the stack trace it comes down to similar function calls using CoreGraphics.

So my question boils down to: What is the best way do draw an image to a window with a framerate > 20fps using wxWidgets on OS X? Currently I use the DrawBitmap() function.

Bonus question: when I have the window on my Macbooks internal Retina screen the framerate gets even worse. Is there maybe any preprocessing/scaling on the picture I should do to take off load from the GUI-process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest is probably to use OpenGL (although I'm less sure about this under OS X which is not very OpenGL-friendly AFAIK), but I'm not really sure if the bottleneck is really `DrawBitmap()`, it could be the code doing the conversion to `wxBitmap` in the first place: if you don't use [raw bitmap access](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_pixel_data.html), it could be quite slow.

Comment: From the Code in the Example I took the approach to do all my image processing in a worker thread that sets the wxBitmap and calls `Refresh()` and `Update()` to trigger the `OnPaint`event on the main-Thread. Is this the right approach or should I directly draw from my worker-thread using the `wxClientDC`?

Comment: No, you can't even touch `wxBitmap` from the worker thread, let alone draw it. All you can do is create `wxImage` (which is a non-GUI class and so is not tied to the main thread) and then convert it to `wxBitmap` and draw it in the main thread. This will only help if receiving data is time consuming too.

Comment: Hm, is "can't" here like "it's asking for trouble" or should it not work at all? Because actually it works quite well. Let alone the example (which is linked from the wxWidgets tutorial page) actually sets the `wxBitmap` from the worker thread (but in a method of `CCamView` which is derived from `wxWindow`). I now changed this to using a `wxImage` and do the conversion to `wxBitmap` in the `onDraw` function. At least I now got rid of the flickering between redraws. But the `drawBitmap` still needs ~110ms for one full screen picture on retina opposed to ~15ms when drawing on a normal screen.

Comment: "can't" is "not guaranteed to work" and in practice this is not going to work under Windows.

Comment: Okay, I think I got that part. I posted my code on [github](https://github.com/heinemml/wxOpenCV). The interesting part is in [camview.cpp](https://github.com/heinemml/wxOpenCV/blob/master/src/gui/camview.cpp). `DrawCam` is called from the worker thread and `Draw`is called from the `OnPaint-Event. Is this implementation how it should be done? It works in general but the `drawBitmap` function takes a lot of time on a 15" retina display in fullscreen (~110ms) and the GUI feels sluggish.

Comment: I just reimplemented this using OpenGL. I now need ~12ms to draw a fullscreen image on a 15" retina display. The time on a none retina display is identical. So I guess there is something seriously wrong with `drawBitmap()` on retina Macs.